# flutter how to Use landscape mode only on certain screens

Tags: flutter

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
  DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, 
  DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
]);
```

I am using the code above to prevent landscape mode on all screens.

What I want is to prevent landscape mode on almost all screens and only use landscape mode on one specific screen.

help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should be a `StatefulWidget`.

Fixed landscape mode in initState() method of specific screen

```
@override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
  }
```

When a widget is dispose()ed, it is fixed in portrait mode.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

being used in the main function

 SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

Should I delete the above code?

Comment: No, I use portrait mode locking code elsewhere, but when a specific page is executed, `initState()` is executed for the first time and landscape mode is fixed. Also, when the page is closed, `dispose()` is executed to change to fixed portrait mode again.

Comment: This is a cycle of `StatefulWidget`.